# magento add to database

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am using flexslider for magento I have added new image fields in add slide page.

I have added three new image browse button, image1, image2, image3

All image get uploaded properly to the folder.

Now I want to add this new image to the database also.

How can I add image name to database in new columns image1, image2 , image3

[image]

can anyone help me how to add this name?

Comment: why you want to add image to database? Is there any specific reason?

In magento, you cant save images to database. You can just save the image path to database and that too it is not suggested any where of adding images to database

Comment: This link may help you: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/admin/how_to_create_pdf_upload_in_backend_for_own_module